# Scale Vega contour data to fit scatter plot dimensions

Tags: d3.js, geojson, vega

Using Vega, I would like to overlay scatter and contour plots such that the global `width` and `height` properties are obeyed.

An attempt can be accessed here ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)) that follows the approach of the documented [contour example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/volcano-contours).

- The base configuration ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sgyb.png)) results if no scaling is applied:

  ```
  "projections": [
     {
      "name": "projection",
      "type": "identity",
      "scale": { "signal": "1" }
    }
  ]
  ```
- It is possible to match the global `width` property ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saC71.png)) via:

  ```
  "projections": [
     {
      "name": "projection",
      "type": "identity",
      "scale": { "signal": "width/volcano.width" }
    }
  ]
  ```
- Similarly, it is possible to match the global `height` property ([image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkgU7.png)) via:

  ```
  "projections": [
     {
      "name": "projection",
      "type": "identity",
      "scale": { "signal": "height/volcano.height" }
    }
  ]
  ```

I currently don't understand how to implement the `fit`, `extent` and `size` arguments of the identity projection ([documentation link](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/projections/)), especially given that `fit` takes a GeoJSON object type.

Is it possible to apply a projection to the contour data that scales both width and height? Or, as a workaround, is it possible to scale the scatter plot axes to match identity-projected contour plot limits?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's luck that identity projection supports scale. Projections is for transmitting from spherical coordinates to planar.

You can rescale coordinates as in my version. But I guess, you need something close to that example [Contour Plot Example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/contour-plot/)
[image]

[Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)